# Android Studio - New virtual device fails during SD card creation

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to create a new virtual device using the AVD Manager on Android Studio, running on Windows 7.

When I click the finish button I receive an error message. Chechking the idea.log I see this:

```
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Invalid argument size '512M' 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -  
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - mksdcard: create a blank FAT32 image to be used with the Android emulator 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - usage: mksdcard [-l label] <size> <file> 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -  
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -   if <size> is a simple integer, it specifies a size in bytes 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -   if <size> is an integer followed by 'K', it specifies a size in KiB 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -   if <size> is an integer followed by 'M', it specifies a size in MiB 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -   if <size> is an integer followed by 'G', it specifies a size in GiB 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection -  
2019-06-07 17:09:59,558 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Minimum size is 9M. The Android emulator cannot use smaller images. 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,559 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Maximum size is 1099511627264 bytes, 1073741823K, 1048575M or 1023G 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,559 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2019-06-07 17:09:59,559 [ thread 48]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

I have tried different values and unit sizes without success.

Also tried to run the command manually with the same error:

```
mksdcard.exe 512M mysdcard.img
```

As I am using the IDE interface I don't have a lot of options and can not figure out the problem. Is there any soluton to it?